# Postgres constraint by value of array field

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have 2 postgres tables:

```
Device_tb
device_id - integer_id, pk
slots     - integer array

Port_tb
port_id  - integer_id, pk
device_id - foreign key to Device_tb
slot      - integer
```

So I need a constraint for Port_tb table when slot field value is limited by foreign Device_tb.slots array values.

Comment: I think you have the wrong data structure for SQL.  It sounds like you need a table that has one row per "device" and "slot".  I would call it `DeviceSlots`.

Comment: maybe, but that table wouldn't contain any information except slots.

Comment: This is called a "junction table" and is an important part of relational database design.